# How to generate a certificate request with SubjectAltNames on IIS 6.0?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, certificate

I'm looking for a way to add a Subject Alternative Name in my certificate request in the IIS 6.0 certificate creation wizard.
It seems I can only fill the Subject field and not the Subject Alternative Name.

Trying to follow this guide (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931351) using certreq.exe doesn't help, it fails without any hint except that it prints its manual.

Any suggestions appreciated, I hope I won't have to export my public key and generate the csr with openssl :/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to add Subject Alternative Names on Windows. If you are submitting the CSR to a certificate authority, they normally allow you to add the SANs on their site so they don't need to be in the CSR. If you are just making a self-signed certificate, you may need to break out OpenSSL. :)

Comment: ok, I'll try with openssl because it's for testing purpose only and i just want a self signed certificate.
Thanks :)

Comment: I just read again your answer and it seems there's a way to add a subjectaltname afterward, I'll try that before exporting the private key, curiosity matters :)